# Can I Control an Excel file, with VBA, from a Python Web Site?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

One of my colleagues seems to think that you can use Python to design a web portal to manage an Excel file with lots of VBA code.  As I know, VBA doesn't work in a web-based environment, such as SharePoint, or ASP.NET, or anything like that.  Is it possible to use Python to create a web portal as an interface for an Excel file with VBA?  If so, can someone please post some links that describe how to set this up?  I did some Googling and didn't find anything on this topic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, python is a dynamic language and excel file is a zip file with connected XML (open xml format). So it is possible to integrate.

Actually, ironpython is place to look for any interaction between microsoft and python world.

Frotnt page google results took me to below links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/

Comment: Yes, I know about the XML format and all.  Can you really run VBA in a web-based environment though?  I'm not sure about that.  I guess I'll have to dig deeper into this.  Thanks.

Comment: Technically it is possible. however, for VBA to run; Excel should be definitely running. maybe a windows service with WCF hosted http endpoint can be used to achieve this. This would have performance problems though. Must Capacity plan before development.